# Ubuntu Phones Availability

Tags: meizu-mx4

I am looking out for the Ubuntu edition Mobile devices, however I am unable to locate any store where I could buy one. I liked the Meizu Pro 5 Ubuntu Edition and would love venture into the rock solid platform over a tiny device.

Could you help me locate a store where I could purchase one?

I am based in Dubai (United Arab Emirates) and open for online purchase.

I did have a look at options available on wiki.ubuntu.com for installing Ubuntu on an Nexus devices, however these devices are low specs.

Comment: I would hardly call the Pro 5 a _tiny_ device. However, if you get an international Android version of one, it's apparently possible to convert it to an Ubuntu phone: https://plus.google.com/103449842981186239877/posts/RBDbK82Lt83

Answer (score 1):

You can check their [Where to Buy page](http://www.meizu.com/en/wheretobuy.html) for available locations.

Unfortunately, UAE/Dubai doesn't even seem to be on there, so I think an official purchase might be out of the question. If eBay (or something similar) is available in your country, check that. You may find it there new if you're lucky.

Other than that, I don't know the import laws of UAE, and I'm not a lawyer, so I can't advise you about buying the phone elsewhere and bringing it back.

Comment: I bet the only import restrictions in UAE are on natural gas and oil.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix well I don't know that, so I don't want to give advice that could get OP in trouble.

Comment: I was trying to be funny. You are right always err on the side of caution. In all seriousness UAE is awash in money and has no local manufacturing sectors to protect nor are they worried about currency devaluation because people buy too many imported goods. They are also away in oil and natural gas I believe which led to my joke those commodities can't be imported.